# Ceiling fan will not turn off wall switch

Tags: ceiling, fans

New ceiling fan.

Black, Red, White & Green wire coming from outlet box.

Ceiling fan has black, blue, white and green wires.

Wall Switch is single.

Connected black/blue 2 black wire. White 2 white and green to green. Light will not turn off from wall or pull chain.

Connected black 2 black, blue 2 red, White to white and green to green. Fan will not shut off from wall switch but will switch off from pull chain.

Previous fan was a dual light and fan and worked from wall switch.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st thing you've done wrong is not taking note of how the old fan was connected - had you done do you could have connected the new fan the same way.

From your description, your wiring appears to follow the standard where block is "always hot" and red is "switches hot".
So anything you want controlled by the switch should be connected to the red wire, and anything you want to *not* be controlled by the switch should be connected to the black wire.

Seems like you want both the light and fan to be controlled by the switch, so connect them both to the red wire and nothing to the black wire (just cap it off with a wire-nut & some tape).

Comment: Update, wall switch only has black and white wire connected to it